# saving the state of switch button in Android

Tags: android

Suppose in android ..i want to switch from activity A to activity B..
In activity B i am turning on multiple no. Of swithes and then returning to activity A ..the whole process is carried out with the help of intents.
But when i again jump to activity B the switch is again back to its default state.
I want to know the best way of saving the state of the switch so that i can get the same state as i leaved it.
If anyone could suggest me anything related to it then it would b great..plz help
Thanku.

Comment: Have a read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html